# adf dynamic region doesn't executes javascripts

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm new at Oracle ADF, when i'm try to use task flow in a dynamic region, the scripts are not initialized. However, when i use same task flow(only one page fragment) as a region on a page, javascripts are executed correctly. Any opinion?

additionally i try to enclose another adf component (Panel group layout or something) of my region and it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please provide some of your works to give detailed information so that people can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your scripts are executed just one time when the first page fragment is loaded. You can put your scripts as af:resource in a component like panelGroupLayout. Please refer to following link: https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/gotcha_when_using_javascript_in